# Extract rows with consecuitive numbers pandas df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe structured in the following way:

```
num   mut
 3     -
 4     -
 5     -
 26    -
 27    -
 30    -
 31    -
 32    -
```

I have to extract the rows with consecutive "num" and put them in others df. In this case, I have to obtain three dfs.

First:

```
num   mut
 3     -
 4     -
 5     -
```

Second:

```
num    mut
 26     -
 27     -
```

Third:

```
num    mut
 30     -
 31     -
 32     -
```

How can I make it?

Comment: must be a dup somewhere: `for _,d in df.groupby(df['num'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()): print(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
m = ~df['num'].diff().fillna(0).le(1)

dfs = [df for _, df in df.groupby(m.cumsum())]
```

```
print(dfs)

[   num mut
0    3   -
1    4   -
2    5   -,    num mut
3   26   -
4   27   -,    num mut
5   30   -
6   31   -
7   32   -]
```

Comment: In this case i obtain a single list, but i want to divide the original df into three different separate dfs. Can you help? @Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @TiaCava Maybe use `df1 = dfs[0], df2 = dfs[1]`